# How to split messages from logfile?

Tags: java

logfile

AAAAAAAA xxxxxxx.PaymentJob - xxxxxx|BATCH_PAYMENT|2021-05-01 12:45:00|17|Success

AAAAAAAA xxxxxxx.PaymentJob - xxxxxx|BATCH_PAYMENT|2021-05-02 13:45:00|16|Success

AAAAAAAA xxxxxxx.PaymentJob - xxxxxx|BATCH_PAYMENT|2021-05-03 14:45:00|176|Success

AAAAAAAA xxxxxxx.PaymentJob - xxxxxx|BATCH_PAYMENT|2021-05-04 15:45:00|76|Success

AAAAAAAA xxxxxxx.PaymentJob - xxxxxx|BATCH_PAYMENT|2021-05-05 16:45:00|25|Success

How do we split the text so that it can be stored in a variable? Please advise or tell me. Thanks you

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class test{

     public static void main (String[] args)throws Exception{
     demoReadall();
     }

     public static void demoReadall(){
          
          try{
               FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("RunningSystem.log");
               BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
               String strLine;
               Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})");
               Matcher matcher;

               while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
                matcher = pattern.matcher(strLine);
                
                 System.out.println (strLine);
               }
               fstream.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                 System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
     }
}
```

Comment: "_How do we split the text..._" - according to which criteria? Which information do you want to extract? What is your expected result from the input you showed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

split() is likely the function you are looking for.
the parameter is a String, in your case probably "|".
It returns a String[], with a new String each time it finds "|" in your original String.
Something like

```
String[] LineArray = strLine.split("|");
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: I have put it in place, the variable strLine is an error.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
        The local variable strLine may not have been initialized

        at test.demoReadall(test.java:22)
        at test.main(test.java:11)

Comment: @3Tom Java does not like simply initializing variables, it likes for you to declare them as well. I would recommend initializing it to " " or something of the like.

Comment: Would you like to write an example? I'm confused. Just starting to write.

Comment: Replace `String strLine;` with `String strLine = " ";

Comment: I have made corrections. Thank you very much.

Comment: If I have answered your question, it would be kind of you to mark my response as the Correct Answer. Glad I could help!